# Struts 2 xml is not working. The Validation is not happenning

Tags: validation, struts2, struts

This is my controller Login.java

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Login extends ActionSupport {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public Login() {
    }

    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is my Login-Validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">

<validators>
    <field name="userName">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>User Name is required.</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
    <field name="password">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message key="password.required" />
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

This is my struts.xml

```
<action name="NewLogin">
    <result>login.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="LoginAction" class="com.strut.Login">
    <result name="success">success.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">fail.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I am using struts2-core 2.5.16 as the maven plugin.

The issue is the controller is not considering my validation.xml. It directly passes to the execute method and goes to the success page.

I have placed the controller and validation xml within the same package.

Could someone help me with it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your file that named "Login-Validation.xml" is error.
Solution:
1. The validation xml file should be named the "Login-validation.xml".
2. The `<result name="input" >fail.jsp</result>` had been changed to `<result name="input" >login.jsp</result>`. This will be better and logical.